Security Concern over AJAX call - use full path or just endpoint
just testing few ajax call and identify that its wether vulnerable JS attack if i use ajax call like this.
option 1
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com/project_folder/user',
    type: "POST",

OR
option 2
$.ajax({
    url: '/project_folder/user',
    type: "POST",

whats the difference between them and what are the security vulnerability i have if i use full path instead just path.
BTW i suggested to use option 2 its more convenient by security perspective.
i suggest developers to use option 2 apart from that strong sanitisation is also required.

What makes you think that this makes any difference in terms of security?

Option 1 utilizes an absolute URL (https://example.com/project_folder/user) for making AJAX calls, directing the request to a specific domain and path regardless of the current page's URL. This is beneficial for cross-domain communication.
Option 2, on the other hand, employs a relative URL (/project_folder/user), making the AJAX request relative to the current page's URL. This approach is more adaptable, especially within the same domain, as it automatically adjusts to changes in domain or path.
Considerations for CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) should be taken into account with Option 1, as it may lead to restrictions when making requests to a different domain. Additionally, hardcoding URLs with Option 1 can reduce flexibility and maintenance ease.
From a security standpoint, Option 2 is often preferred within the same domain due to reduced risks of unintended requests to other domains, simplified URL management, and adherence to security best practices by limiting requests to the same origin unless explicitly required otherwise.
It is recommended to sanitize user input used in constructing URLs or form parameters to enhance security measures.
references :
Stackoverflow, Relative vs absolute path, Absolute vs Relative Path - Which Should You Be Using?, How-to-make-secure-AJAX-call

"From a security standpoint, Option 2 is often preferred" - do you have any reliable source for that claim? Option 1 (using a specific domain) looks way more explicit in terms of "reduce risks of unintended requests to other domains", as the domain to be used is clearly specified?

Option 2 is frequently favored for security reasons, mainly due to the distinction between relative URLs and absolute URLs in web applications. Here's the rationale behind this preference. Using relative URLs provides a way to avoid hard-coded domain dependencies, enhancing the flexibility and reducing the reliance on specific domain configurations for your application. This becomes especially crucial in scenarios where domains are prone to change, such as development, staging, and production environments, or when the application requires deployment across various domains or subdomains.

Relative URLs streamline the process of development and maintenance, enabling code to be easily transported and reused across various scenarios such as development, testing, and production. Moreover, they mitigate the chances of errors arising from domain names that are hardcoded and not in sync with the actual deployment environments. also its best practice things will learn eventually hope it will clear your doubt @NicoHaase in addition i can temper with JS code anythime from browser console.

Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it, and share reliable sources, especially if you already know that your approach is "frequently favored"

I tried to understand which of the links you've referenced really backs the claim that one way is more secure than the other, but I did not find any such information. They solely mention that moving the application to a new domain is more easy (which, as you linked to other questions on StackOverflow, is nothing new for SO). Can you finally provide some credible sources for the security parts?
